# Vertica backup error

Tags: backup, vertica

I try to do full backup on Vertica database. When I execute command:

```
/opt/vertica/bin/vbr.py --debug 3 --task backup --config-file vertica_backup.ini
```

I am getting following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: ulimit: Illegal option -u
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/vertica/bin/vbr.py", line 2526, in backup
  prepareAll()
File "/opt/vertica/bin/vbr.py", line 1888, in prepareAll
  configCheck()
File "/opt/vertica/bin/vbr.py", line 506, in configCheck
  concurrency_upperboud = int(subprocess.Popen(['ulimit -u'], 
shell=True, stdout= subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].strip())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
backup failed unexpectedly!
```

My vertica_backup.ini file:

```
[Misc]
snapshotName = vertica_backup
restorePointLimit = 1
passwordFile = vertica

[Database]
dbName = dwh_vertica
dbUser = dbadmin

[Transmission]

[Mapping]
v_dwh_vertica_node0001 = vertica1:/home/dbadmin/backups
```

It's Debian Wheezy:

```
Linux vertica1 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1~bpo70+1 (2015-06-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

/bin/sh points to /bin/sh -> dash

Answer (score 0):

I've found workaround, in the Vertica backup file /opt/vertica/bin/vbr.py I have changed ulimit -u to ulimit -n.